# Why "checked" property and v-model can not be used together in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to know why "checked" property in a series of input checkbox elements become unaccessible if v-model is used in these elements in Vue.

Recently I tried to add CheckAll functionality to a list of items.
Without v-model it's trivial:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checkAll">
<div class="list">
  <input v-for="item in items" :value="item.id" type="checkbox" :checked="checkAll">
</div>
```

But if I add v-model "toRemove" to each item in order to get an array of checked items, checkAll checkbox stops working:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checkAll">
<div class="list">
  <input v-for="item in items" :value="item.id" type="checkbox" :checked="checkAll" v-model="toRemove">
</div>
```

It's interesting that "disable" property works well with V-model in a similar manner:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checkAll">
<div class="list">
  <input v-for="item in items" :value="item.id" type="checkbox" :disabled="checkAll" v-model="toRemove">
</div>
```

I wonder why Vue does not allow both checkAll and an array of checked items via v-model at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Using `v-model` on a checkbox sets the `checked` property. You can't set `checked` to two different values at the same time.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html for more explanation of how `v-model` works with checkboxes.

In your case you would implement the check-all functionality just by populating the array `toRemove` with all the relevant item ids.

Using `:checked="checkAll"` to implement check-all functionality isn't really the right way to do it even if you aren't using `v-model`. There's a basic assumption baked into your template that all the checkboxes are either checked or unchecked, rather than being independent checkboxes. This may have appeared to work in a simple test case but ultimately it was never likely to hold together once you tried to make the checkboxes do something for real.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I've guessed that both methods of setting the same property couldn't be used at the same time. Finally, I prefered the simplest way for checkAll button and getting all checked values from the list with vanilla JS.

Comment: @OlegBolden I strongly recommend you do not resort to vanilla JS to solve this problem. If you're going to do that you might as well not bother using Vue.